# No scrollbar after starting a `gnu-screen` session in WSL

Tags: gnu-screen, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL) on Windows 10. I can use the scrollbar with mouse or touchpad before starting a screen session. But, once I start a screen, I lose the scrollbar (gray out).

What I did:

1. Increase the buffer size from property 50 -> 900 (no effect)
2. start `screen` with `-h` option like `screen -h 50 or 1000` (no effect)

tmux seems to have the same problem.

Interestingly, when I ssh into a remote server (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11), `screen` actually works fine in the same Ubuntu 18.04 WSL shell.

So, I feel there must be a way to get this working in WSL.

version info:

WSL
Screen version 4.06.02
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release

SUSE
Screen version 4.00.02
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(2)-release

WSL is using more recent versions of bash and screen.

Both `.screenrc` files are near empty and contain no configuration related to buffer size or scrollbar.

I know that `Ctrl + A, ESC` to enter the copy mode and then scroll up/down with the keyboard (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760452/566035). But this does not give me a scrollbar and mouse/touchpad do not work in this mode.

Any solution??

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the general solution for `gnu-screen` actually worked for WSL.

As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125947/566035), adding this magic line below to `.screenrc` fixed the issue.

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

P.S.

To increase the screen buffer size, right-click the title bar of WSL and go to `Properties` and `Layout` tab and increase the `Height` of Screen Buffer Size (ex. to 800).